# Using constrain for inputView of a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` and I added inputview to it

```
 [textField setInputView:inputView];
```

I added some buttons along with date picker in input view. Input view has `UIDatePicker` as subview. Since the inputview is not added as subview to any other view, I cannot set height constrain for inputView. How to deal with constrain for inputview of a `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you not need to set constraint for input view. because it is take default place of `keyboard`.

You should show date picker as input view and you should take toolbar as `inputaccessory view` of textfield and add buttons to that `tool bar`,so you not need to manage layout and it is the standard way also.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I added some buttons and date picker to input view.

Comment: You should show date picker as input view and you should take `toolbar` as `inputaccessory view` and add buttons to that tool bar

Comment: Thanks 'Lion'  . It is working after I added 'inputaccessoryview' to 'UITextfield'.